# How to show custom info window on map view

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I need to show a custom info window when I click on a pin.

The pin is directly in style on the layer.

When I creating a map Im getting the style by url:

```
        mapView?.getMapAsync { map ->
            map.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromUrl("mapbox://styles/my-style")) {
                onMapReady(map)
            }
        }
```

Then I define this layer:

```
    fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap
        val layer = mapboxMap.style?.getLayer("my-layer")
        layer?.setProperties(visibility(Property.VISIBLE))
        mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(this@InfoWindowSymbolLayerActivity)
    }
```

OnMapClick method:

```
    override fun onMapClick(point: LatLng): Boolean {
        return mapboxMap?.projection?.toScreenLocation(point)?.let { handleClickIcon(it) }!!
    }
```

HandleClickIcon method:

```
fun handleClickIcon(screenPoint: PointF): Boolean {
        val features = mapboxMap?.queryRenderedFeatures(screenPoint, MARKER_LAYER_ID)

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val bubbleLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pin_info, null) as BubbleLayout

        val type = features?.get(0)?.getStringProperty(type)
        bubbleLayout.tvDefectType.text = type?.let { formatType(it) }

        val username = features?.get(0)?.getStringProperty(username)
        bubbleLayout.tvDefectInfo.text = username?.let { formatDefectInfo(it) }

        val measureSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        bubbleLayout.measure(measureSpec, measureSpec)

        val measuredWidth = bubbleLayout.measuredWidth.toFloat()

        bubbleLayout.arrowPosition = measuredWidth / 2 - 5

        val bitmap = SymbolGenerator.generate(bubbleLayout)

        type?.let { mapboxMap?.style?.addImage(it, bitmap) }

        mapboxMap?.let {
            it.getStyle { style ->
                setUpInfoWindowLayer(style)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Mapbox example uses custom GeoJson:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-info-window/

But I need to display the info window above the 
[pin like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuPWY.png) on click

Comment: Well you have method `onMarkerClick` (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/5.0.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html). The info window do not have to be placed in map view, just create your own above and show when needed.

Comment: `onMarkerClick` doesn't triggered when i click on a map @Ikazuchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the layer is already in your style, then you don't need to set its visibility to visible with `layer?.setProperties(visibility(Property.VISIBLE))`. It's already going to be visible.

I'd follow https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-info-window/ by:

- Starting the data loading and bubble window `SymbolLayer` setup earlier in your code, rather than in `onMapClick`: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/InfoWindowSymbolLayerActivity.java#L88
- Only changing the select state in `onMapClick`: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/InfoWindowSymbolLayerActivity.java#L186-L206

Comment: The first url is down (it shows http 404) ...